# How to add a parameterized return type of function in Java Poet

Tags: java, javapoet

How would I generate a method with the following signature?

```
public ServiceA<? extends ServiceB> anyFunctionName() {
    // code
}
```

**Problem**:
Not sure how to add return type : `ServiceA<? extends ServiceB>`

Assuming I have FQCN for ServiceA and ServiceB.

What I am trying is code below, but does'nt work.

```
 MethodSpec.Builder builder =
            MethodSpec.methodBuilder("anyFunctionName")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
  .returns(ParameterSpec.builder(ParameterizedTypeName.get(
                    ClassName.bestGuess("com.learn.ServiceA"),
                    WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Object.class),
                    ClassName.bestGuess("com.learn.ServiceB")).build());
```

The above code generates the following code:

```
public ServiceA<? , ServiceB> anyFunctionName() {
        // code
    }
```

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Assume they are just Factory classes giving FQCN.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: JavaPoet library generates Java codes as output. Hence 

" public ServiceA<? extends ServiceB> anyFunctionName() {
    // code
} "

this function is the desired output code that I want to generate.

Comment: @Michael any help

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. This helped. I was unnecessary putting WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Object.class) !! It worked now.

Comment: No problem, glad I could push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, @Michael for pointing out the mistake I was doing.

Following code worked.

```
MethodSpec.Builder builder =
            MethodSpec.methodBuilder("anyFunctionName")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
  .returns(ParameterizedTypeName.get(
                    ClassName.bestGuess("com.learn.ServiceA"),
                    WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(ClassName.bestGuess("com.learn.ServiceB")));
```